# Why use a mosfet instead of potentiometer?

Tags: led, mosfet, potentiometer

A mosfet is being used to increase and decrease the current across an ir led and resistor (in series) circuit. The voltage across the circuit is changed to increase or decrease current flowing through it so that the intensity of ir led can be changed. What I don't understand is why don't we use a potentiometer instead of mosfet which is more economical and will increase and decrease the current just the same... So why use a mosfet??

Comment: Horses for courses. If you want a constant voltage you use a voltage regulator, if you want a constant current you use something else.

Comment: You don't have the photo o the circuit, but you can edit your question and use the button with the diode-capacitor-resistor symbol to create a schematics.

Comment: @next-hack I don't see such buttons in editing... I'm using it in a phone

Comment: @finbarr doesn't the constant voltage gives constant current??

Comment: Into a linear load like a resistor, yes, but an LED is not a linear device and current varies hugely with voltage in its active region.

Comment: @finbarr but there is a resistor in series with led to control that varying current

Comment: In which case is the MOSFET simply used to switch the LED on and off? Or set the brightness using PWM? Without a schematic all we can do is guess.

Comment: @finbarr set the brightness means using mosfet as an amplifier to get better signals?

Comment: @GunjanGangwani A resistor in series with a LED still can't be controlled with voltage alone. The resistor typically acts as a feedback to then precisely control the current. I wouldn't know that if I wasn't just working on such a thing.

Comment: *Circuit: it somewhat looks like this...* Geez, there is a circuit editor you know, use it!

Comment: @GunjanGangwani - It will **really** help readers if you can supply a clear, readable circuit diagram (schematic) of the circuit for which you want help. If you cannot use the built-in circuit editor due to accessing this site via your phone, then you can: Draw the schematic clearly and correctly on white paper using a black pen (for maximum contrast); take a photo of that drawing using your phone, making sure that your phone is perpendicular (i.e. at 90 degrees) to the paper; try to only include the drawing and not blank paper in your photo; then edit your question and upload that image.

Comment: No, I'm talking about using a MOSFET as a switch to turn the LED on for part of the time and off for the rest, but do it so quickly that you don't see it flash. The amount of time it spends on compared to off varies the brightness.

Answer (score 1):

Contained within a voltage regulator is a form of silicon device acting as a pass transistor, be it a BJT or a MOSFET. Sometime the current rating is too much for a common regulator & thus such a device must be constructed out of discretes to reach the desired operating point

[image]

[image]